# DateFormatter localized date format printing "PM" when it should be "AM"

Tags: swift

Here's a reduced version of my formatter class:

```
class MyDateFormatters {
    let timeFormatter : DateFormatter
    init(timeZone:Int) {
        self.timeFormatter = {
            let tz = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: timezone)
            let df = DateFormatter()
            df.timeZone = tz
            df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("hhmm")
            return df
        }()
    }
}
```

In my `viewDidLoad`, I'm deriving a time string from raw data. But it's coming out wrong in a weird way: I'm seeing "PM" where I should see "AM"!

Here's the raw data (comes in thru JSON):

```
    let timeZone = -14400
    let sunriseRaw = 1570620145
```

Now, if just make a plain vanilla date formatter and print out `sunriseRaw`, this is what I get:

```
    let sunrise = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(sunriseRaw))
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    df.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: timeZone)
    print(df.string(from: sunrise))
    // 07:22 AM
```

And that is correct. Okay, now I'll do with *my* date formatter:

```
    let myf = MyDateFormatters(timeZone:timeZone).timeFormatter
    let sunriseString = myf.string(from: sunrise)
    print(sunriseString)
    // 7:22 PM
```

How can this be? My class is doing exactly the same thing, except that it uses a localized date format with a template. Why am I seeing "PM" instead of "AM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been caught by an unbelievably obscure bug in your code. Look very, very closely:

```
init(timeZone:Int) {
//       ^
    self.timeFormatter = {
        let tz = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: timezone)
//                                            ^
```

So the `timezone` you are using in your formatter is not the same as the `timeZone` that arrived as parameter into your initializer.

So, you may, ask, what *is* `timezone`? Why didn't the compiler flag it? Sigh, it's because Foundation injects the entirety of C / Darwin into your code. `timezone` is a Darwin value. Open *time.h* and you'll see it. Tricky, eh?

(Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to get the compiler to warn about this kind of thing. Using Darwin values without explicit namespacing is legal, and you wouldn't want it not to be.)

Comment: Btw, Xcode uses different colors for the (global variable) `timezone` and the (local parameter) `timeZone`. Also the “quick help” shows a small difference: `var timezone` vs `let timeZone`.

Comment: @MartinR What actually alerted me was something the playground said when I moved everything there and tried to work out what was happening; it said there was an ambiguity, and I was like, "huh?" :)

Comment: Yes, there is a `extern long timezone` variable, a `struct timezone`, and a `char *timezone(int zone, int dst)` function :)