# Initializer element is not a compile-time constant (XCode 12.5.1 - time.h / timezone)

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, time.h

I have a very old project that rotted away since around OS X 10.6 and which I'm trying to revive. It has a piece of code that I can summarise like so:

```c
#include <time.h>
// ... 
void *pFunc = timezone; // at the global scope
// ...
```

XCode 12.5.1 complains with this error:

> Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

I tried to use *gcc* in the Terminal with the most basic test code:

```c
#include <time.h>

void *pFunc = timezone;

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

This produces the error with this:

- Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)

The project uses `timezone` in the global scope, as demonstrated by the sample code.

What is the easy fix, if there is one?

Comment: Isn't timezone a long int? And isn't it indeed not a constant?

Comment: @matt The code wants to get a function pointer. `timezone` is a `extern long timezone __DARWIN_ALIAS(timezone);` (time.h), where `#define __DARWIN_ALIAS(sym)             __asm("_" __STRING(sym) __DARWIN_SUF_UNIX03)` (cdefs.h). Normally it would be a `char *timezone(int, int)`. It's the definition of `__DARWIN_UNIX03` that flips to the non-constant definition because of some symbol mangling.

Comment: Eyeroll: https://linux.die.net/man/3/timezone says:
"4.3BSD had a function char *timezone(zone, dst) that returned the name of the timezone corresponding to its first argument (minutes West of UTC). If the second argument was 0, the standard name was used, otherwise the daylight saving time version." Playing around, I can see that `timezone` is indeed just a `long`, and not a function at all now.

Comment: Well they may both exist. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58328023/341994 where I stumbled into this too.

Comment: @matt It's unlikely they both can exist, as the variable is active `#if __DARWIN_UNIX03` while the function is active on the reverse, `#if !__DARWIN_UNIX03`. Your problem was actually caused by using the wrong case for the letter 'Z', which led you to use the symbol I have trouble with. If this symbol hadn't existed you would have seen a undefined variable error.

Comment: Well, MartinR's comment mentions the function too.

Comment: Yep. His comment looks handwavy though, as you can't have two different with the same name in C. The availability of one over the other depends on which side of the time barrier you are: The BSD4.3 side, or the UNIX03 side. In my test program, setting __DARWIN_UNIX03 to 0 gives me the function, but the resulting binary doesn't work - it crashes with a bus error.